# How to get Multi-select value Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, captcha

I have added below code in my config.xml file to add one option in Magento multi select captcha section

```
<default>
    <customer>
        <captcha>
            <always_for>
                <custom_faq>1</custom_faq>
            </always_for>
        </captcha>
    </customer>
    <captcha  translate="label">
        <frontend>
            <areas>
                <custom_faq>
                    <label>FAQ</label>
                </custom_faq>
            </areas>
        </frontend>
    </captcha>
</default>
```

It look like this.
[image]

Now I want to get value of this multi-select option. How can I get this multi select value?

Comment: Nice point that you have raised. +1 for that. And thanks for accepting my answer

Comment: You welcome @ShoaibMunir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configuration value would save in comma separated values so you can explode it to get it in array form

Try this code:

```
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName');
$configValue = explode("," $configValue);
```

the final `$configValue` would be an array